# Why do my rosa chinensis flowers turn white as they age?

Tags: flowers, roses

I've got 5 rosa chinensis outside my window and they get about 10 hours of direct sun in conditions of about 39°C and 13% humidity. I water them 1.5 litres per day, and feed them with a bloom special (it has a nutrition chart if needed) every 10 days.

The problem is that newborn flowers (I don't know the technical term :D) are colorful and in colors of orange and red.

[image: colorful]

but they become white and a bit green after a while.

[image: white]

Comment: Surprisingly enough, many rose breeds change colour during bloom (often "getting paler"), this is sometimes a trait that is specially selected when breeding.

Comment: You've said Rosa chinensis, but there's usually a cultivar or varietal name added afterwards - rosa chinensis is the rose from which many cultivars have been created, so which one have you got, specifically?

Comment: @Bamboo I have no idea, the seller told me that 4 of them are called 'sanaz' which I searched for and found that it's rosa chinensis and the seller also told me that one of them is called miniature rose.

Comment: Mahdi...just one idea to throw in here...you need to cut these flowers off before the petals begin to curl!!  This will promote even more flowers...is there a problem with the different colors?  Very normal.  Your plant looks healthy but is this in a pot in your home, on the patio, what is your watering schedule, fertilizer???

Comment: @stormy the problem's with all flowers no matter which color or which plant. the pot is outside my room window. and I water them 1.5L per day at 6PM which is not directly sunny then. And I give them 30ml of a bloom special every 10 days and it contains:
total nitrogen 12%, Organic soluble Nitrogen 10%, available phosphate (P2O5) 5%, soluble potass (K2O) 35%, Boron 0.1%, Cu 0.1%, Manganese 0.1%, Zinc 0.1%

Comment: Mahdi...first I am reading that you water every day?  How big is this pot, how hot does it become and how much light. Also sounds a bit overkill on fertilizer.  Too much nitrogen and I am sure that the potassium 35% is a typo?  Yes?  These look like a sedum -like plant.  Holding moisture within its cells for use during dry periods, like a cactus?  Watering everyday can't be good?  Please send a couple more pictures...thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said you don't have cultivar names for your roses, so its hard to be specific without that information. Rosa chinensis is the first part of the name of many cultivars or varieties, but there is one called R. chinensis 'mutabilis' - I'm not suggesting that's yours, but that particular variety produces flowers which start out a honey coloured yellow, change through to coppery pink, then more sort of watermelon colour ending up a mahogany shade. Its probably safe to assume that your particular rose has a similar habit, and this change of colour in the flowers is quite normal, though it might not be an effect you would have chosen had you known about it!

There might be some bleaching going on though - some roses retain their colour better and longer in shadier conditions, or at least with not so much sun as yours are getting.